# vscode error: References to interface static methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to use AWS Java SDK.v2 but I get the following error:

[image]

What I have tried so far :

1. Using the same code with Intellij and it works just fine.
2. I know with Eclipse you can set compliance level from the following section as shown below:

[image]

3. In my vscode user settings, I have set :

   ```
   "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
   ```

Environment

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
JDK version: OpenJDK 11.0.6 2020-01-14
Visual Studio Code version: 1.41.1
```

Since I'm using vscode, how can I set the compliance level?

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it has solved my issue as well. You may want to also upvote this issue on the vscode-java-maven repository: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-maven/issues/748

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to solve the error above by doing the following :

1. In my pom.xml, I've added the following:

   ```
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>
   ```
2. In my project structure, there's an extension named "***org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs***" which is located at .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs. I modified it as shown below:

   ```
   eclipse.preferences.version=1
   org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
   org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
   org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
   org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
   ```